# Template literal causing unrecognized token error

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord.js

I'm writing a discord bot using Discord.js and I'm experimenting with SQLite before adding it into my main project. I've more or less followed [this guide](https://anidiotsguide_old.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/content/coding-guides/storing-data-in-an-sqlite-file.html) and then modified the code to closer resemble my goals for the main project.

there is one piece of code that is causing problems:

```
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"`).then( row => 
{
  if ( row )
  {
    let nufu = JSON.stringify( new foo() );
    sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET object = ${nufu} WHERE userId = ${message.author.id}`);
  }
  else
  {
    sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, object) VALUES (?,?)", [message.author.id, JSON.stringify( new foo() )] );
  }
}).catch( () => {
  console.error;
  sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, object TEXT)");
});
```

Specifically `${nufu}` is causing:

> (node:12348) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: unrecognized token: "{"
> (node:12348) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

replacing `${nufu}` with `"any_other_string"` eliminates the error but `${JSON.stringify( new foo() )}` does not,

`${message.author.id}` causes no such problems.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What exactly does `nufu` (stringified) look like?

Comment: Well your rendered literal is going to look something like `object = {}` which isn't valid sql, did you mean to surround it in quotes so it is stored as a string? ie `object = '${nufu}'`

Comment: {"fa":1,"fb":6,"fc":7}

Comment: `'${nufu}'` has done it, and makes me feel like an idiot to boot... Thanks Patrick.